# $.post always returns initiated view from mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

from my razor edit view I'm hitting mvc controller action where I'm returning ActionResult View.

```
$.post('/products/details/', { id: someId });  

public ActionResult Details(id)
{
   ...
   return View();// in breakpoint this is hitted but never returned as this view.
}
```

It's always returns me on page where jquery post is initated.

Comment: you have to pass the object you want to edt as argument `return View(object);`

Comment: what do you mean with "returns me"? `$.post` makes an ajax async call. There is no redirect involved...

Comment: Ajax calls stay on the same page. If you want to update the DOM with the view returned by your method, then you need to handle the success callback (but it would need return a `PartialView` anyway

Answer (score 3):

`$.post` without a callback is like ordering a Pizza then going to bed and forgetting about it. The delivery guy leaves it on the doorstep, where it then gets dragged away by dogs and you never see it :)

Basically: *The result of an Ajax post is ignored unless you do something with it*.

e.g.

```
$.post('/products/details/', { id: someId }, function(htmlReturned){
   // Do something with the page HTML returned
   $('body').html(htmlReturned);  // e.g. replace the entire page!
});
```